# testing a component when using NzModalFooterDirective

Tags: angular, testing, modal-dialog, jestjs, ng-zorro-antd

I have a simple component that I want to test. I load this component from another as a modal:

```js
 const modal = this.modalService.create({
     nzContent: MyModalComponent
    });
```

The component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-modal-component',
  template: `

<div *nzModalFooter>
  <button nz-button nzType="default" (click)="destroyModal()">
    Cancel
  </button>
</div>
`
})
export class MyModalComponent{

  constructor(private modal: NzModalRef) {}

  destroyModal(): void {
    this.modal.destroy({});
  } 
}
```

When creating the test bed for the `MyModalComponent` component, I get the error:

```
 NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[NzModalFooterDirective -> NzModalRef]:
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NzModalFooterDirective -> NzModalRef]:
        NullInjectorError: No provider for NzModalRef!
```

Reading the error I tried to use the `NzModalFooterDirective`.

```js
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [OtherModules],
      declarations: [MyModalComponent],
      providers: [
        NzModalFooterDirective
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

And any other import:

```js
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [OtherModules],
      declarations: [MyModalComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: NZ_MODAL_CONFIG, useValue: {} },
        NzModalService,
        NzModalFooterDirective
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

Without success...

I also tried to use NzModalRef directly

```js
describe('MyModalComponent', () => {
  let component: MyModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyModalComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [OtherModules],
      declarations: [MyModalComponent],
      providers: [NzModalRef]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

but then I get the error: 
`this.nzModalRef.getInstance is not a function`

I just want to prepare the test bed. I am not sure if I import the `NzModalRef` wrong or if I have to replace it with a custom mock.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bypass this error, you can simply mock the `NzModelRef` by `useValue`

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: NzModalRef,
    useValue: {
      getInstance: () => {
        return {
          setFooterWithTemplate: () => {}
        };
      }
    }
   }
]
```

In your case

```
describe('MyModalComponent', () => {
  let component: MyModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyModalComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [OtherModules],
      declarations: [MyModalComponent],
      providers: [{
         provide: NzModalRef,
         useValue: {
          getInstance: () => {
            return {
              setFooterWithTemplate: () => {}
            };
          }
        }
      }]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`NzModalRef` is dynamically injected in `NzModalComponent`, you don't need to declare it to the `providers`.

Comment: Thank you that you took the time. Any Idea how to get rid of the `NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule) NzModalFooterDirective -> NzModalRef]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core) NzModalFooterDirective -> NzModalRef]: NullInjectorError: No provider for NzModalRef!`error

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to set a provider for `NzModalRef` creating a new modal with a factory:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        OtherModules
      ],
      declarations: [MyModalComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: NzModalRef,
          useFactory: (modalSvc: NzModalService) => modalSvc.create({
            nzClosable: false,
            nzContent: MyModalComponent
          }),
          deps: [NzModalService]
        }
      ]
    }).overrideModule(BrowserTestingModule, {
      set: {entryComponents: [MyModalComponent]}
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

It is also needed to add the modal component to the entry components.